# Method Interception to get property name

Tags: java, reflection, proxy-classes, method-invocation, method-interception

I am looking for a utility class or library that gives me the name of the property in a type-safe way. I have something similar like the following in mind:

```
PropertyDescriptor descriptor = property(on(Foo.class).getBar());

assertThat(descriptor.getName()).isEqualTo("bar")
```

To have such a convenience method implemented properly requires IMHO quiet a lot of work. As the handling of final classes and the like can be extremely complex (see mockito, easymock etc.)

Comment: When talking about properties and reflection on Java beans, the first thing that comes to my mind is the [Apache Commons BeanUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/) lib. But I don't know if you can solve your exact problem by using it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [QueryDSL's aliases](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/4.0.1/reference/html_single/#alias) as:

```java
import static com.querydsl.core.alias.Alias.*

Foo foo = alias(Foo.class, "foo");
assertThat($(foo.getBar().getBaz()).getMetaData().getName()).isEqualTo("foo.bar.baz");
```